# What is wrong with my gnome-3?

Tags: gnome

I have gnome 3 installed. 
It looks like this :

[image]

But I want it to look like this :

[image]

Isn't it supposed to anyway ?

Additional information : 
I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. 
I installed gnome using apt-get install command from the terminal.

also :

[image]

Please help me !

Comment: I have zero experience with Intel, but if there is a proprietary driver for your GPU available, install it. It seems you are now using VESA drivers, and those don't have hardware acceleration, which is required by gnome 3.

Answer (score 1):

You're running the Gnome Fallback desktop (Gnome Panel). It's not the same desktop as Gnome Shell. This is usually because of missing drivers. You might want to look for proprietary drivers.

Comment: ummm .. I do not actually have a graphic card. So I dont see there is any point in looking for drivers ? Also, I cannot run the gnome shell without a graphic card ? This sucks. Unity is better then I suppose. offers more features without the graphic card.

Comment: You have some kind of graphics and even if it's on your motherboard, it requires drivers. We can them graphic cards all the same, whether they're modules or integrated.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the [Gnome ppa](https://launchpad.net/~gnome3-team/+archive/gnome3) typing in the terminal:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3`
`sudo apt-get update`

and install the stable gnome-shell:

`sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

[*more gnome3 ppas*](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuGNOME/Developers)